# Do railroads on a different continent give the production bonus?

Tags: civilization-5

The in-game help states that:

> Connecting Cities to your capital by
>   Railroad will give them a 25%
>   Production bonus.

If the city in question is on a different continent, this would seem impossible.  Does the link formed by a Harbor count for purposes of this bonus?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If your harbor is connected via railroad to your capital, the harbor connection counts as a railroad. You'll have then to lay railroads from your harbor on the other continent to any inland cities.

In the following example B,C and D would receive the bonus, E would not.

```
                   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ 
|A|============|B|~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~|C|===========|D|
                   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  |
                                  `------------|E|
```

In the next example no city would receive the railroad bonus.

```
                   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
|A|------------|B|~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~|C|===========|D|
                   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  |
                                  `------------|E|
```

As DMA57361 pointed out, if the capital has a harbor, any other city with a harbor automatically receives the railroad bonus. In the next example, C and D receive the bonus, E does not.

```
                   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~
               |A|~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~|C|===========|D|
                   ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~ ~  |
                                  `------------|E|
```

**Legend:**

```
 A : capital
 = : railroad
 - : road
 ~ : ocean
```

Comment: This also works if your capital is on a coast and has a harbour, every other harbour city is "connected by railroad" and receives the bonus - even if you don't build a single hex of railroad.